# MarkLogic search:search not returning snippets

Tags: search, marklogic

I am doing a `search:search` on a MarkLogic database.  I can search on the term "**pineal**" and return 297 results with snippets.  I can search on "**city:Vancouver**" and return 83 results with snippets.  The query "**pineal OR city:Vancouver**" returns 374 results with snippets.  However, the query "**pineal AND city:Vancouver**" returns a count of 6 results, but no result elements and no snippets.  Any idea why I am not getting result text?

Thanks!
Ravi Har

Comment: Can you provide some sample XML that you expect the query to match?

Comment: Also, how is that "city:" constraint defined?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have found the problem.

The xml being searched looks like this:

```
<lecture objectType="lecture">
    <city>Vancouver</city>
    <state>British Columbia</state>
    <country>Canada</country>
    <formattedTranscript>
        <body class="lecture-transcript" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        ...
```

The city constraint looks like this:

```
<constraint name="city">
    <range type="xs:string" facet="true">
        <element ns="" name="city"/>
        <facet-option>frequency-order</facet-option>
        <facet-option>descending</facet-option>
    </range>
</constraint>"
```

I had the following statement in my $options declaration:

```
<searchable-expression>
    //(formattedTranscript|title|city|state|country|objectDate)
</searchable-expression>
```

When I take this statement out the search returns results as expected.  I'm curious why the searchable-expression statement breaks the search results.

Thanks everyone for your comments.

Comment: I fixed the XML formatting for you. (Click on "edit" to see how to format code properly.) You can just edit your existing answers, no need to post a new one.

Comment: The searchable expression isn't breaking the search results exactly; it's making the count inaccurate. The count is generated based on the unfiltered (basically a shortlist documents that might match) results, whereas the actual results you see are filtered, that is; checked to remove the false-positives. In this case, checking that the potential matches are within the searchable expression is part of the filtering process; thus a count that is too high. You might also see low counts if (say) there is more than one `city` in a document; each document is only counted once in the estimate.

Comment: You might ask, why return elements like city and state as individual results. Doesn't it make much more sense to just return lecture as results, and allow search:search to give you snippets of the interesting bits? It would also allow you to show results as a list of lectures while showing things like city and state as mere meta data details of lectures, like they are.

Comment: Or are you using that search expression to limit searches to the content within those elements? There are better ways to do that. I think a field would be most appropriate here. Go to the database configuration in the Admin interface. More details can be found here: http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/fields#chapter